# How do I view *all* of my historical questions?

Tags: support, questions

How do I view my complete question history?  I'm looking at [image] but I can't see a way to change the date range.

Also in the past when I clicked on my name, the questions were shown right then.  This time I got the screen shown in the image.

Comment: I am assuming using your profile to view all your question is not enough for what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not click on your name. You clicked on the envelope next to your name.

What you clicked was your site activity at the following URL:

```
http://superuser.com/users/recent/XXX
```

To show your profile and all the questions and answers you've posted, click on your DisplayName, which leads to a URL like this:

```
http://superuser.com/users/XXX
```

Comment: thanks.  This is my second embarrassment of the day, I'm going for 3.  Given that I've clicked the name in order to see my question about 300 times I should have remembered.  But I'm going to make a suggestion to the powers that be that regardless of how you get to your profile you should be able to see everything associated with you without going to the top menu.  Any way to change to see your questions within the profile itself?

Comment: No, different pages show different information. @how

Answer (score 7):

Follow the arrows.

[image]

If the above image is blocked - here's the steps to view your questions:  go to your [user profile page](https://superuser.com/users/12894/howiecamp), click on the stats tab and you'll see the questions.

Comment: Please explain "image is blocked"?

Comment: I meant if you cannot view the image due various reasons (webfilters at work, imgur down et al)